# R: set value differences within grouped data from top row vs. all the rest

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

Say we have this dataframe:

```
product    price
a          2.0
a          1.8
a          1.9
b          2.4
b          2.2
b          2.6
c          1.6
c          1.2
c          1.2
```

My goal will be to -once having grouped the data by `product`, to create an additional column which should store to what extent does `price` differ from each group's top row to the subsequent ones. In other words, this:

```
product    price    diff
a          2.0      0.0
a          1.8      -0.2
a          1.9      -0.1
b          2.4      0.0
b          2.2      -0.2
b          2.6      0.2
c          1.6      0.0
c          1.2      -0.4
c          1.2      -0.4
```

Is there any simple and smooth solution to achieve this?

Comment: `df %>% mutate(diff = price - first(price), .by = product)`